# Set Theory and Equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$ and $X$ be sets. Show that $X\setminus(X\setminus A)\subseteq A$, and that equality holds if and only if $A\subseteq X$.

I understand why this holds but am not sure how to 'show' this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by explaining in ordinary words your understanding of why it holds. We'll figure out what's missing for it to be a proper proof afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the definition/alternate expression for "setminus": $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$, where $B^c$ is the complement of $B$:
$$X\setminus(X\setminus A)=X\cap (X\cap A^c)^c = X\cap (X^c \cup A) = (X\cap X^c) \cup (X \cap A)= X\cap A$$
Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Define that $A\subseteq X  \,\,\Leftrightarrow\,\, \forall x\in  A \Rightarrow x\in X$

Pain attetion that: $X\backslash A\Leftrightarrow x\in X$ **and** $x\notin A$.

and, by De morgan, $(X\backslash A)^c \Leftrightarrow x\notin X$ **or** $x\in A.$

$X\backslash(X\backslash A)\Leftrightarrow x \in X \,\,\text{and}\,\, x\notin (X\backslash A)\Rightarrow x\in X$ and $x\in (X\backslash A)^c\Rightarrow x\in X$ and $(x\notin X$ or $x\in A)\Rightarrow x\in X$ and $x\in A \Rightarrow x\in A$.

For the equation I need to prove the inverse (remember that $A\subseteq X$ is true):

$A\subseteq X\backslash(X\backslash A)$.